# curl -d equivalent in Node.js http post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, curl

I know that the command

```
curl -X POST -d 'some data to send' http://somehost.com/api
```

can be emulated in Node.js with some code like

```
var http = require('http');
var post_data = 'some data to send',
    headers = {
        host: 'somehost.com',
        port: 80,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/api',
        headers: {
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
        }
    };

var request = http.request(headers, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    });
});
request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("An error ocurred!");
});
request.write(post_data));

request.end();
```

The question is because I'm looking for the equivalent in node of the cURL command

```
curl -d name="Myname" -d email="myemail@gmail.com" -X POST http://somehost.com/api
```

how can i do that?

This is because I wanna do a POST request to a [Cherrypy server like this one](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/REST.html), and I'm not able to complete the request.

**EDIT** The solution, as @mscdex said, was with the request library:

I've resolve the problem with the request library. My code for the solution is

```
var request = require('request');

request.post('http://localhost:8080/api', {
  form: {
    nombre: 'orlando'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(err, res);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could encode it manually:

```
var post_data = 'name=Myname&email=myemail@gmail.com';
```

Or you could use a module like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to handle it for you (becomes especially nice if you have to upload files) since it will handle data escaping and other things for you.

Comment: You're right. I've resolve the problem with the request library. My code for the solution is

    var request = require('request');
    
    request.post('http://localhost:8080/api', {
      form: {
        nombre: 'orlando'
      }
    }, function(err, res) {
      console.log(err, res);
    });

Thank you!